# Is there a .endswith that can open files with suffix variations after (".html?") (e.g. go through ".html?p=1209401", ".html?p=92030", etc.)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, ends-with

I'm trying to create an html parser that will take all the html and htm files in a folder and its subfolders and take out all html tags and export CSV and TXT files.  I have a folder with subfolders that have numerous files in them that end with ".html?p=39200" or "index.html?replytocom=5467"

I'd like to tell Python open all files with ".html?" + * (including any variation after that) not just ".html" files.

I've tried googling, looking at the docs, and stack overflow but can't find a solution to this problem. So far here is that bit of my code:

```
with os.scandir(directory) as it:
    for entry in it:
        if entry.name.endswith(".html") or entry.name.endswith("htm"):
```

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner

Answer (score 1):

You could check that the string `".html"` appears anywhere in the filename, not just at the end:

```
with os.scandir(directory) as it:
    for entry in it:
        if ".html" in entry.name:
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try this out and report back

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to get the part before the question mark (or the whole file name if it does not contain a question mark), and use that part to match against '.html' and 'htm':

```py
with os.scandir(directory) as it:
    for entry in it:
        name = entry.name.split('?')[0]
        if name.endswith(".html") or name.endswith("htm"):
            print(entry.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also with a regular expression.

```
import re
with os.scandir(directory) as it:
    for entry in it:
        if re.match(r'.*?(?:\.html?$|\.html?\?.*)', entry.name) is not None:
```